# Special characters in AWS api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've created a lambda based API Gateway on Amazon Web Services. Unfortunately some of these API replies with special charachters, that appear not to be correctly encoded:

```
{"id":222,"address":"Gloriastrasse","country":"","city":"ZÃ¼ric",...
```

This is supposed to be, of course, Zürich. Is there some way to solve this issue?
Data is correct when is retrieved from DB.

Comment: What content type are you using for your response mapping?

Comment: @BobKinney application/json